# Is it possible to attach a game key to multiple Battle.net accounts?

Tags: battle.net

**Is it possible to attach a game's authentication key to multiple Battle.net accounts?**

Say I have a Starcraft II: Wings of Liberty authentication key. Can I create a new Battle.net account, attach that key to it (register/activate it). Then, *if need be*, un-register it from that account, and attach that same key to another Battle.net account?

Comment: You are referring to CD keys (game licenses), and not Blizzard Authenticators (security token generators), correct?

Comment: Correct, cd keys is what I mean.  Although, on the actual game box, the term used is "Authentication key".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Game keys cannot be attached to two battle.net accounts.  (trying to do so gives a message saying that that key is already in use)
- Game keys cannot be unregistered or transferred by any user options. (The interface has nothing of the sort)

If this needs to be done, you'd have to contact Blizzard customer support, but I'm not sure they'll let you. They might though.

Update:

After re-reading through the TOS, there are two separate "licenses" involved (from a legal perspective), the license to use the game client, and the account to play with. The account cannot be sold. The client can be transferred, but the new owner would have to purchase a new account, that is supposedly available at blizzard.com or battle.net

(I am not a lawyer, my advice is not legal advice)

Comment: does that implicitly mean, I can't sell the game?

Comment: Do you have a link to where you found those bullets?

Comment: I tried to source those bullets with the stuff in parentheses, it's not amazing sourcing, but it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: And yes, that does mean that you can't sell the game. But IIRC, the terms of service does mention how transferring an entire account would work. Again, for something like that, I'd recommend talking to a Blizzard customer support representative to take care of it.

Comment: @Stampede You can sell the game, but if the buyer wants to be able to use Battle.Net, you would have to be willing to give them your Battle.Net account.

Comment: AFAIK the buyer would not be able to play *at all*.  Just having the disc is not enough to play - the game also must be registered with your Battle.net account, and you must log in with it registered at least once to play offline modes.

Comment: So, Blizzard has been known to, in the past, with proof of ownership (owning and physically mailing, the slip of paper that has the key on it) transferred ownership of an account.

Comment: imho any company which charges for a physical product should recognize the physical product as the IP rights too - that is, if you have a CD for the game, you should own the game and if you don't have the CD, you don't own the game.  If Blizzard does allow you to transfer accounts, as McKay suggests, then I will be very happy and willing to pay for their games.

Comment: Blizzard does not allow any transfer of account ownership, per the terms of service (http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/about/termsofuse.html), and they attempt to make it tricky to do so (you can't change the security email address without calling support).

I don't like it, but they really don't want you giving away or re-selling games

Comment: @Mechko the physical product does not contain the full IP, it requires an online component.  If I shipped you a twitter client, I could not guarantee IP rights to twitter as I do not own twitter.  The disc does contain IP rights to the client, but not to the online service.

Comment: @Tzenes yes this is true, but my point still stands.  You pay for *the use of* both IP's, but you are still given a physical product which is the key to said IP.  Both sides can be argued pretty successfully, but in the end, I dislike the rising policy of companies to artificially 'consume' products that are reusable.  Waste and redundancy in the digital world may not be as big a sin, but take a look at iOS4 as an example.  I'm a great fan of mac products, but the iphones and ipod touches are artificially retired by bloating the software.  Consumable IP is only one part of the problem facing--

Comment: --cont'd consumers today.  Companies are forcing us to discard resources that are otherwise fully functional and usable by implementing extra-normal restrictions on them.  In the end we, the buyer, are losing our right to ownership and more and more becoming slaves to a corporate machine.  The societal dialectic is dying because more and more, those who were once elements of society are becoming pieces of capital.  Marx claimed that there was an end to dialectics.  This one is a little chilling.  My 2c worth.

Comment: Effectively another example of the Chilling Effects of [Digital Restrictions Management](http://drm.info/)